# jQuery Closest usage

Tags: jquery

We have:

```
<div class="companylinks">
   <span class="current">
      <a class="welcome">Welcome!</a>
   </span>
   <span>
      <a class="ic_generalinfo">General Info</a>
   </span>
</div>
```

I want to get the class of the `<a>` which is in the `<span class="current">` (here is 'welcome')

```
var selected_tab = $('#companylinks span[class="current"]').closest('a').attr('class');
alert(selected_tab);
```

But I'm getting 'undefined', how I should ise closest() here?

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Will there ever be only one `a` inside the `span`?

Comment: @JanHančič Yes, only 1 a

Comment: Please read the manual first, before posting questions: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.closest()` goes up the parent chain, not down the parent chain.

To specify multiple parents that all must be satisfied in a selector, you can just list them separately in the selector separated by spaces.  In this case you can target the `<a>`tag inside of .current and then obtain its class like this:

```
$(".current a").attr("class");
```

Or, if you want to scope it only to inside of `.companylinks`, then you can use this;

```
$(".companylinks .current a").attr("class");
```

Note: You don't need to use `span[class=".current"]`.  You can just use `.current`.

Answer (score 3):

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) only traverses up in the DOM, not down. You may want to use something like `children`.

There are other errors in your code; you're currently accessing `#companylinks`, which should be `.companylinks`, seeing as that is a class name and not an ID. Other than that, your `span[class="current"]` could be written as `span.current`, although that's not an error.

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` function gets the closest **parent** not closest **child**. to get what you want simply do this:

```
$('a.welcome')
```

Or if you need more specificity:

```
$('.current a.welcome')
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation of .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing **the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors** in the DOM tree.

Write this instead

```
$('.companylinks span.current').find('a').attr('class');
```

Comment: Why use `.find()` here when you can just put the `a` right in the selector?

Answer (score 0):

Hey man if you want only that anchor element you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var selected_tab = $('.companylinks .current').find('a').attr('class');
alert(selected_tab);
});
```